# When i enabled https sites stop working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to nodejs  and i have installed ubuntu on nodejs 
**and i have SSL certificates from comodo as well**

I followed following steps

```
1) Login to root account and copy the key file in SSL cert to  /etc/ssl/private/private.key file.
2) Then created file called /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_cert.com.crt and paste  the contents of STAR_cert_com.crt into it.

3) Then create file called /etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt file and paste all the contents of three files present inside "CA and Intermediate Certs" folder.
```

And after that i configured my app.js file as follwoing

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/STAR_cert_com.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false 
};

var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen(443, function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port : " + app.get('port'));
    console.log("Mode : " + app.get('mode'));
});

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(80);
var secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen(443, function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port : " + app.get('port'));
    console.log("Mode : " + app.get('mode'));
});
```

When i run my website example.com it redirects to https://example.com and gives me following error

```
>     This webpage is not available
>     
>     DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

But no error on server console.

If i run website without https website is working fine

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have added certificates with wrong key. 
Double check the files  and their key pair. if you have intermediate certificates include that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the key and cert parameters of sslOption json as string, for example, you can easily startup a https nodejs server using express 4+ with something like:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('your.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('your_crt.crt').toString()
  };
  var https = require('https').Server(options,app);
  https.listen(config.port, function() {
    console.log('Server started successfully');
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you get the same error using the server ip addres instead the domain name?